# Installing hardhat on an Amzon EC2 instance or on any live server

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, aws

I want to deploy and maintain contracts from an ec2 instance, didn't choose lambda for time constraints reasons.

I could translate everything to ethers js except contract verification which proves a little bit more tricky.

So the question is, would it be a good idea to have hardhat running on the server?

Lets assume the server is an EC2 instance for now